# Convert dictionary to JSON string with saving "None" value as "None" and not "null"

Tags: python, json

I have a dictionary that contains data written in Ukrainian and a field with `None`.

```
{"city": "АДАМІВКА", "state": None}
```

I need to convert it to a string. I tried to use `json.dumps` which resulted in

```
json.dumps({"city": "АДАМІВКА", "state": None})
json.dumps({"city": "АДАМІВКА", "state": None}, ensure_ascii=False).encode('utf8').decode()

{"city": "\u0410\u0414\u0410\u041c\u0406\u0412\u041a\u0410", "state": null}
{"city": "АДАМІВКА", "state": null}
```

Is there any way to save any `None` value as `None`, not `null`, so that the result would be `str` formatted `{"city": "АДАМІВКА", "state": None}`?

Comment: Then it wouldn't be JSON anymore.

Comment: The short answer is no. The definition of `json` allows a `null` value. `None` is not part of `json`.

Comment: What is the problem with having `null` and not `None`?

Comment: Now that you have `null` values in your `json` strings means that you will allow **any** other `json` parser to understand what value is there.

Comment: Do you want `None` as a string inside the JSON like `{"state": "None"}`, as others already mentioned, if not the JSON will not valid

Comment: If you want to create a format which resembles JSON but really isn't, probably `import json` and subclass it.  From memory, I believe you should find it relatively easy to replace the `None` serialization handler.

Comment: Why do you want `None` instead of `null`? If your goal is to treat the JSON as valid Python code you could assign `null = None`.

Comment: I need to send it to API that requires None there, they convert this str and somehow save it to their Database. Yeah I know it's weird but I can't do anything about it

Comment: So, why bother with `json`? Why not just call `str()` on your `dict`?

Comment: Honestly, I'm not sure why I guess I was too focused on json. Thank you!

Comment: @SerhiiStets Which one Adamivka is mentioned here? There are several localities with this name in Ukr.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I need to convert it to a string.

If that's the goal there is no need to use json. Python has a builtin function for that: [`str()`](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_func_str.asp)

```py
>>> str({"city": "АДАМІВКА", "state": None})
"{'city': 'АДАМІВКА', 'state': None}"
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you need `None` as a string in your resulting JSON
you can go through your Dict and replace a `None` with a `"None"`

```
import json

d = {'state': None}
print(json.dumps(d))
# {"state": null}

for k in d:
    if d[k] is None:
        d[k] = 'None'
print(json.dumps(d))
# {"state": "None"}
```